# СSS свойство пагинации, зависящее от другого элемента страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, пагинация

Есть пагинация на сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом расположить пагинацию, чтобы она примыкала к нижней границе объемлющего элемента? Т.е. в css-свойствах пагинации

```css
#pagination {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#pagination li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#pagination li:hover, #pagination li.active {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

в `#pagination` в свойстве `margin-top:` должно быть `$('.centerarea').height - totalblockheight - heightunderpagination - paginationheight`, где `totalblockheight` - суммарная высота блоков - карточек товаров, расположенных над пагинацией, `heightunderpagination` - высота под пагинацией, `$('.centerarea').height` - высота объемлющего блока, `paginationheight` - высота самой пагинации. Каким образом в css-файле можно задать свойство `margin-top` элемента `#pagination` (кроме динамического задания свойства в js через атрибут style)?

Comment: За что минусовали? Вопрос вполне нормальный и нормально сформулирован. Даже в рекламе над вопросом написано "Не стыдись спросить - не знать еще постыднее".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `flex`
Должна быть такая структура примерно

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="products">
  </div>
  <div class="pagination">
  </div>
</div>
```

И такие стили

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: а что делать, если элементы блока `products` должны располагаться вплотную, а `pagination` впритык  к нижней границе  и на некотором расстоянии от последнего элемента блока `products`?

Comment: Подтягивайтесь все кто может.

Comment: products это контейнер для продуктов, они будут вплотную, а вот как раз между этим контейнером и пагинацией будет это расстояние